# How do i decrease value inside html tag using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery : `$('#entrycount').val() -1;`
My HTML:

```
<div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 text-right">
      <span>Total Entries </span>
      <h2 id="entrycount" class="font-bold">
        <%= Count%>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I am unable to reduce the numeric value using jquery. I want to decrease the value in side h2 tag.

Comment: `val()` is only used for form controls, not content elements

Answer (score 1):

Use `text()` instead of `val()` which is only used on form control elements

```js
$('button').click(()=>{
  $('#entrycount').text((_, curr) => curr - 1)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Decrease count</button>

<div class="widget style1 navy-bg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 text-right">
      <span>Total Entries </span>
      <h2 id="entrycount" class="font-bold">
        20
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```